# call_user_func_array("shell_exec", ...) not working in php

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec, call-user-func-array

In php, when I call

```
shell_exec('ls');
```

it executes the commands 'ls' in shell and returns a string which consists of set of files in the directory

But when I call

```
 call_user_func_array('shell_exec', 'ls');
```

it is always returning false. What mistake am I doing?

Comment: The second argument to `call_user_func_array` is supposed to be an array.

Comment: it says so in the function name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second parameter to the function `call_user_func_array()` should be an array.

```
<?php
    if(call_user_func_array("shell_exec", array("ls")))
        echo "TRUE";
    else
        echo "FALSE";
```

works as expected.